# select option to fetch other inputs

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What Im trying to do is select item name where is ID and if item selected it automatically adds that item serial number to `serial number` input.

I think it should be used ajax maybe but I dont know how exactly.

```
Item Name:<br />
<div class="select-holder">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    <?php
    if($_items->count_items() == 0)
        echo '<select name="item-name" disabled><option value="no">You need to add a item first</option></select>';
    else{
        echo '<select name="item-name" id="change-item">';
        $items = $_items->get_items_dropdown();
        while($item = $items->fetch_object()) {
            echo "<option value=\"{$item->id}\">{$item->name} - {$item->serialnumber}</option>";
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }
    ?>
</div>
Serial Number:<br />
<div class="ni-cont">
    <input type="text" name="item-serialnumber" class="ni" disabled/>
</div>
```

I have also other inputs like `description`, `price` and etc.. to fetch these inputs with these values.

example: i need get data to my field from select option id (value)

```
<input type="text" name="item-serialnumber" value="<?php echo $_items->get_item_serialnumber($id); ?>" class="ni" disabled/>

<input type="text" name="item-serialnumber" value="<?php echo $_items->get_item_description($id); ?>" class="ni" disabled/>
```

Comment: Hi, you need to fetch `{$item->serialnumber}` value ?

Comment: example i've fetched select option where is item id, name and serial number. If user selects one of options then it fills my inputs with selected ID. Like ID makes new query to database to fetch all needed data.

Comment: In your question you have `it automatically adds that item serial number to serial number input...`or `ID` ? Also, did you tried something to achieve that  please update your question with that as well.

Comment: Inside select option yes there is serial number, but I want add this serial number also into  serial number input.

You can see I have two fields, one is select option field and another is serial number input field. And I want fetch serial number to that input value

Comment: Example: `<input type="text" id="idss" name="item-serialnumber" value="<?php echo $_items->get_item_serialnumber($id); ?>" class="ni" disabled/>` 

This code cant work because I dont know how to give it ID.

Comment: Edited post....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That value is already shown inside your select-box you can simply use `onchange` event and then use `$(this).find("option:selected").text().split('-')[1]` this will give serial no then put it inside your input-box using `$('[name=item-serialnumber]').val(somevalue)` .Also ,you can send `id` via ajax to your server page and fetch result.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#change-item").on("change", function() {
  var value = $(this).find("option:selected").text().trim().split('-')[1]
  $("[name='item-serialnumber']").val(value)
  var id = $(this).val();
  //use ajax :

  $.ajax({
    url: "somepgaename.php", //the page containing php script
    type: "post", //request type,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      id: id //send id as well
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data.yourfieldname);
      //put inside your input fields values like :
      // $("[name='item-serialnumber']").val(data.serialno)
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Item Name:<br />
<div class="select-holder">
  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  <select name="item-name" id="change-item">
    <option value="1">Abc-123</option>
    <option value="2">Abc2-122</option>
    <option value="3">Abc2-132</option>
  </select>
</div>
Serial Number:<br />
<div class="ni-cont">
  <input type="text" name="item-serialnumber" class="ni" disabled/>
</div>
```

Then , at your server end get the `id` pass via ajax using `$_POST['id']` then fetch result using *select* query and send them back to ajax using `echo json_encode($somearray);` i.e:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id=:id");
$stmt->execute(['id' => $id]); 
//put fetch result inside array..send back to ajax 
//echo json_encode($somevalue);
```

Comment: But problem is there still, because I have to get all data from that selected item. example i have to insert data to serial number field, description field, price field, etc.. Your function would work only if all these data variables are in select option.

Comment: I think best way is to get id and fetch it from database each field.

Comment: I see so can you use ajax here ?

Comment: Yes I can use ajax

Comment: I have updated my answer with sample code . Please check it and let me know if any error you got.

Comment: `require 'config.php';
$id = $_POST['id'];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = :id");
$stmt->execute(['id' => $id]);
$data = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
echo json_encode($data);` it doesnt give any info to console. I use `console.log(data)`

Comment: is there any error inside browser console.

Comment: Nope. clear. i've tried console id, value and still empty.

Comment: Instead of `echo json_encode($data);` simply send `echo json_encode("somestring");` check if this comes . Also , check your network tab > XHR section it will give you ajax call  infos

Comment: are you sure ajax run ? and your event handler are gettting called ? put `console.log(id)` inside event handler see if this gets printed.

Comment: Seems like this `$("#change-item").on("change", function() {` because console doesnt give `id` or even `console.log("give info")` still empty.

Comment: `$("#change-item").on("change", function() {
    console.log("change");
    var value = $(this).find("option:selected").text().trim().split('-')[1]
    console.log("value: " + value);
    $("[name='item-serialnumber']").val(value)
    var id = $(this).val();
    console.log("id: " + id);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227545/discussion-between-swati-and-kmb67116).